# Backstage view in outlook 2007

Tags: outlook-addin, outlook-2007, outlook-2010, outlook-2007-addin

I am developing an outlook 2007 add-in which is based on an existing outlook 2010 plugin. I managed to get most of the features working, because most of them were backwards compatible. However there are some I could not, because 2007 simply did not have certain features. \

1. Backstage view
2. Main ribbon

My question is - what would you suggest for an equivalent interface? Where would you put in outlook 2007 something that was in backstage view in 2010?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much deliberation I decided to use a custom menu. All features available through the backstage view in 2010 will be converted to menu items in the custom menu in Outlook 2007.

Also buttons from the main ribbon will become items in the same custom menu.

This solution, while not as elegant as Fluent UI will work, I think, because all of my plugin's functionality will be available from one spot.